# beanshell equivalent of continue

Tags: java, beanshell

Is there a beanshell equivalent of java continue ? ex :

```
if(...cond){
dosomething();
continue;
}
```

If question is not clear I mean continue keyword from this example :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ContinueDemo.htm

Is there something similar in beanshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

> continue;

Comment: that would be awesome I haven't tried it I'm writting java code now and when I write it I'll then transfer it to execute it in beanshell

Comment: You are talking about continue as it relates to a for loop?  Basically if this condition is true move to next element?

Comment: I'm talking about for inside for/while loop yes